# Save image from Open GL

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am new in Open GL, and I writing some program to android, which change image with a shaders. I load image like texture and change that, but I don't know how save changed image. Can I save changed image or maybe I can get pixels from texture?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `glReadPixels` function, documented [here](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml).

Bear in mind that this operation can be slow: the GPU is originally made and optimized to receive data *from* the CPU, process it and display it; sending data back from the GPU to the CPU is an unusual operation, that is not as optimized.

Comment: If i correctly understand this method, he gets pixel from all view. Can I get pixels only from my object, on which I imposed texture?